CDK - Configuring an ECS Fargate container with secret from Parameter Store without a Cloudformation parameter being created
I'm trying to migrate my existing ECS cluster to CDK and am having issues with secrets.
In my original definition JSON, it's configured using valueFrom as below:
"secrets": [
    {
        "name": "SECRET_ENV_VARIABLE",
        "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:XXXXXXXX:parameter/path/to/parameter"
    }
]

where /path/to/parameter is a SecureString parameter, but when I try to replicate this in CDK (C#) as follows:
var definition = new FargateTaskDefinition(this, "TaskDefinition", new FargateTaskDefinitionProps
{
    Cpu = 256,
    MemoryLimitMiB = 512,
    Family = "definition-family",
});

definition.AddContainer("ServiceTask", new ContainerDefinitionOptions
{
    ...
    Secrets = new Dictionary<string, Secret>
    {
        { "SECRET_ENV_VARIABLE", Secret.FromSsmParameter(StringParameter.FromStringParameterName(this, "SecretEnvVariable", "/path/to/parameter")) }
    }
});

I get Parameters [/path/to/parameter] referenced by template have types not supported by CloudFormation.
Looking at the generated template, I see the valueFrom entry as in my original JSON, but I also see a generated Cloudformation parameter:
"SecretEnvVariable2A88BA98": {
   "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
   "Default": "/path/to/parameter"
}

This Cloudformation parameter is not referenced anywhere in the template, so is there a way I can achieve the same valueFrom output without the problematic Cloudformation parameter?

Try using fromSecureParameterAttributes instead.

@gshpychka thank you! I'm not sure how I missed that. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it.

You are using a Secure String parameters, not a regular String Parameter, so you should be using StringParameter.fromSecureStringParameterAttributes() instead of StringParameter.fromStringParameterName()
